# Is TanStack Query/ react-query using ReactJs useState under the hood?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I been looking through the [code](https://github.com/TanStack/query/tree/main) & it seems that TanStack uses observers to notify completion of HTTP requests. I see there a is concept of [setState](https://github.com/TanStack/query/blob/main/packages/query-core/src/query.ts#L216) but I have yet to [connect the code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ATanStack%2Fquery+setState&type=code) to a call to ReactJs `setState`.

In this code below, there is no parents, prop changes or state to cause re-render, yet, when `data` changes 1 second later, a re-render indeed occurs.

I am trying to understand if it is `TanStack Query` that has abstracted away ReactJs executions that trigger the re-render or if my functional component has "reacted" to the reference of `data` changing.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';

function asyncFunc() {
  console.log('DBG-asyncFunc');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('done');
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function onClick() {
  window.location.reload();
}

const Sandbox = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['whatevs', {}],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const result = await asyncFunc();
      return result;
    },
    ...{ staleTime: 0, cacheTime: 0 },
  });

  console.log('DBG-a-render', data);

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Async Value: {data}</h4>
      <hr />
      <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
        Reload
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sandbox;
```

Comment: Tanstack Query uses [useSyncExternalStore](https://react.dev/reference/react/useSyncExternalStore) to cause the component to rerender. Does that answer your question? Here's the line of code: https://github.com/TanStack/query/blob/df089941a156c12057dba2ee8bb15f52aa2a9f4f/packages/react-query/src/useBaseQuery.ts#L72